# Compile error, when building tensorflow v1.14.0 without avx2 support

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, gcc, build, bazel

Using Debian 10 Buster, Python v2.7.
I try to build specific tensorflow v1.14.0 without avx2 support, because I get following error:

> Nov  4 17:12:32 moodle37 kernel: [9773297.574293] traps:
>   python2.7[4570] trap invalid opcode ip:7fb9b74bca59 sp:7ffdb7605e10
>   error:0 in libtensorflow_framework.so.1[7fb9b6d97000+18f8000]

1) I cloned tensorflow with git

2) checked out v1.14.0.

```
>git status
HEAD detached at v1.14.0
```

3)

```
gcc -Q -march=native --help=target | grep march
  -march=                               nehalem
```

So CPU codename is nehalem.

4) I used `./configure`
with build options:

```
-march=nehalem mavx -msse4.1 -msse4.2 -mpclmul -mpopcnt -maes -mno-avx2
```

5) Executed

```
bazel build //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

but I got build error:

```
ERROR: /root/inst/tensorflow_src/tensorflow/core/kernels/BUILD:3255:1: C++ compilation of rule '//tensorflow/core/kernels:matrix_square_root_op' failed (Exit 1)
gcc: fatal error: Killed signal terminated program cc1plus
compilation terminated.
Target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
INFO: Elapsed time: 18990.253s, Critical Path: 381.93s
INFO: 2372 processes: 2372 local.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

6) Executed

```
bazel build --verbose_failures //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

with following error:

```
ERROR: /root/inst/tensorflow_src/tensorflow/core/kernels/BUILD:3255:1: C++ compilation of rule '//tensorflow/core/kernels:matrix_square_root_op' failed (Exit 1): gcc failed: error executing command
  (cd /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/d7c6443e63bbc3c61de28c70992e7b9c/execroot/org_tensorflow && \
  exec env - \
    PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin \
    PWD=/proc/self/cwd \
    PYTHON_BIN_PATH=/usr/bin/python \
    PYTHON_LIB_PATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages \
    TF_CONFIGURE_IOS=0 \
    TF_DOWNLOAD_CLANG=0 \
    TF_NEED_CUDA=0 \
    TF_NEED_OPENCL_SYCL=0 \
    TF_NEED_ROCM=0 \
  /usr/bin/gcc -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -fstack-protector -Wall -Wunused-but-set-parameter -Wno-free-nonheap-object -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g0 -O2 '-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1' -DNDEBUG -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections '-std=c++0x' -MD -MF bazel-out/k8-py2-opt/bin/tensorflow/core/kernels/_objs/matrix_square_root_op/matrix_square_root_op.pic.d '-frandom-seed=bazel-out/k8-py2-opt/bin/tensorflow/core/kernels/_objs/matrix_square_root_op/matrix_square_root_op.pic.o' -fPIC -D__CLANG_SUPPORT_DYN_ANNOTATION__ -DEIGEN_MPL2_ONLY '-DEIGEN_MAX_ALIGN_BYTES=64' '-DEIGEN_HAS_TYPE_TRAITS=0' -DTF_USE_SNAPPY -iquote . -iquote bazel-out/k8-py2-opt/bin -iquote external/com_google_absl -iquote bazel-out/k8-py2-opt/bin/external/com_google_absl -iquote external/eigen_archive -iquote bazel-out/k8-py2-opt/bin/external/eigen_archive -iquote external/local_config_sycl -iquote bazel-out/k8-py2-opt/bin/external/local_config_sycl -iquote external/nsync -iquote bazel-out/k8-py2-opt/bin/external/nsync -iquote external/gif_archive -iquote bazel-out/k8-py2-opt/bin/external/gif_archive -iquote external/jpeg -iquote bazel-out/k8-py2-opt/bin/external/jpeg -iquote external/protobuf_archive -iquote bazel-out/k8-py2-opt/bin/external/protobuf_archive -iquote external/com_googlesource_code_re2 -iquote bazel-out/k8-py2-opt/bin/external/com_googlesource_code_re2 -iquote external/farmhash_archive -iquote bazel-out/k8-py2-opt/bin/external/farmhash_archive -iquote external/fft2d -iquote bazel-out/k8-py2-opt/bin/external/fft2d -iquote external/highwayhash -iquote bazel-out/k8-py2-opt/bin/external/highwayhash -iquote external/zlib_archive -iquote bazel-out/k8-py2-opt/bin/external/zlib_archive -isystem external/eigen_archive -isystem bazel-out/k8-py2-opt/bin/external/eigen_archive -isystem external/nsync/public -isystem bazel-out/k8-py2-opt/bin/external/nsync/public -isystem external/gif_archive/lib -isystem bazel-out/k8-py2-opt/bin/external/gif_archive/lib -isystem external/protobuf_archive/src -isystem bazel-out/k8-py2-opt/bin/external/protobuf_archive/src -isystem external/farmhash_archive/src -isystem bazel-out/k8-py2-opt/bin/external/farmhash_archive/src -isystem external/zlib_archive -isystem bazel-out/k8-py2-opt/bin/external/zlib_archive -DEIGEN_AVOID_STL_ARRAY -Iexternal/gemmlowp -Wno-sign-compare -fno-exceptions '-ftemplate-depth=900' -msse3 -pthread -fno-canonical-system-headers -Wno-builtin-macro-redefined '-D__DATE__="redacted"' '-D__TIMESTAMP__="redacted"' '-D__TIME__="redacted"' -c tensorflow/core/kernels/matrix_square_root_op.cc -o bazel-out/k8-py2-opt/bin/tensorflow/core/kernels/_objs/matrix_square_root_op/matrix_square_root_op.pic.o)
Execution platform: @bazel_tools//platforms:host_platform
gcc: fatal error: Killed signal terminated program cc1plus
compilation terminated.
Target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package failed to build
INFO: Elapsed time: 3559.068s, Critical Path: 448.60s
INFO: 397 processes: 397 local.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

EDIT1:

```
191105 20:22:26.151:I 1354 [com.google.devtools.build.lib.exec.local.LocalSpawnRunner$SubprocessHandler.start] starting local subprocess #314, argv: /usr/bin/gcc -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -fstack-protector -Wall -Wunused-but-set-parameter -Wno-free-nonheap-object -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g0 -O2 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 -DNDEBUG -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -std=c++0x -MD -MF bazel-out/k8-py2-opt/bin/te...tin-macro-redefined -D__DATE__="redacted" -D__TIMESTAMP__="redacted" -D__TIME__="redacted" -c tensorflow/core/kernels/matrix_square_root_op.cc -o bazel-out/k8-py2-opt/bin/tensorflow/core/kernels/_objs/matrix_square_root_op/matrix_square_root_op.pic.o
191105 20:22:26.151:I 1354 [com.google.devtools.build.lib.exec.local.LocalSpawnRunner$SubprocessHandler.stepLog] prefetching inputs for local execution (#314 Compiling tensorflow/core/kernels/matrix_square_root_op.cc)
191105 20:22:26.151:I 1354 [com.google.devtools.build.lib.exec.local.LocalSpawnRunner$SubprocessHandler.setState] Step #314 time: 0.001 delta: 0.001 state: PARSING --> PREFETCHING_LOCAL_INPUTS
191105 20:22:26.152:I 1354 [com.google.devtools.build.lib.exec.local.LocalSpawnRunner$SubprocessHandler.stepLog] running locally (#314 Compiling tensorflow/core/kernels/matrix_square_root_op.cc)
191105 20:22:26.152:I 1354 [com.google.devtools.build.lib.exec.local.LocalSpawnRunner$SubprocessHandler.setState] Step #314 time: 0.002 delta: 0.001 state: PREFETCHING_LOCAL_INPUTS --> LOCAL_ACTION_RUNNING
191105 20:29:22.020:I 1354 [com.google.devtools.build.lib.exec.local.LocalSpawnRunner$SubprocessHandler.setState] Step #314 time: 415.868 delta: 415.866 state: LOCAL_ACTION_RUNNING --> SUCCESS
191105 20:29:22.363:W 1354 [com.google.devtools.build.skyframe.AbstractParallelEvaluator$Evaluate.run] Aborting evaluation due to com.google.devtools.build.lib.skyframe.ActionExecutionFunction$ActionExecutionFunctionException: com.google.devtools.build.lib.actions.AlreadyReportedActionExecutionException: C++ compilation of rule '//tensorflow/core/kernels:matrix_square_root_op' failed (Exit 1): gcc failed: error executing command
  (cd /moodledata/inst/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/ebeb582d6679e454bd341748991b8998/execroot/org_tensorflow && \
  exec env - \
    PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin \
    PWD=/proc/self/cwd \
    PYTHON_BIN_PATH=/usr/bin/python \
    PYTHON_LIB_PATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages \
    TF_CONFIGURE_IOS=0 \
    TF_DOWNLOAD_CLANG=0 \
    TF_NEED_CUDA=0 \
    TF_NEED_OPENCL_SYCL=0 \
    TF_NEED_ROCM=0 \
  /usr/bin/gcc -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -fstack-protector -Wall -Wunused-but-set-parameter -Wno-free-nonheap-object -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g0 -O2 '-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1' -DNDEBUG -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections '-std=c++0x' -MD -MF bazel-out/k8-py2-opt/bin/tensorflow/core/kernels/_objs/matrix_square_root_op/matrix_square_root_op.pic.d '-frandom-seed=bazel-out/k8-py2-opt/bin/tensorflow/core/kernels/_objs/matrix_square_root_op/matrix_square_root_op.pic.o' -fPIC -D__CLANG_SUPPORT_DYN_ANNOTATION__ -DEIGEN_MPL2_ONLY '-DEIGEN_MAX_ALIGN_BYTES=64' '-DEIGEN_HAS_TYPE_TRAITS=0' -DTF_USE_SNAPPY -iquote . -iquote bazel-out/k8-py2-opt/bin -iquote external/com_google_absl -iquote bazel-out/k8-py2-opt/bin/external/com_google_absl -iquote external/eigen_archive -iquote bazel-out/k8-py2-opt/bin/external/eigen_archive -iquote external/local_config_sycl -iquote bazel-out/k8-py2-opt/bin/external/local_config_sycl -iquote external/nsync -iquote bazel-out/k8-py2-opt/bin/external/nsync -iquote external/gif_archive -iquote bazel-out/k8-py2-opt/bin/external/gif_archive -iquote external/jpeg -iquote bazel-out/k8-py2-opt/bin/external/jpeg -iquote external/protobuf_archive -iquote bazel-out/k8-py2-opt/bin/external/protobuf_archive -iquote external/com_googlesource_code_re2 -iquote bazel-out/k8-py2-opt/bin/external/com_googlesource_code_re2 -iquote external/farmhash_archive -iquote bazel-out/k8-py2-opt/bin/external/farmhash_archive -iquote external/fft2d -iquote bazel-out/k8-py2-opt/bin/external/fft2d -iquote external/highwayhash -iquote bazel-out/k8-py2-opt/bin/external/highwayhash -iquote external/zlib_archive -iquote bazel-out/k8-py2-opt/bin/external/zlib_archive -isystem external/eigen_archive -isystem bazel-out/k8-py2-opt/bin/external/eigen_archive -isystem external/nsync/public -isystem bazel-out/k8-py2-opt/bin/external/nsync/public -isystem external/gif_archive/lib -isystem bazel-out/k8-py2-opt/bin/external/gif_archive/lib -isystem external/protobuf_archive/src -isystem bazel-out/k8-py2-opt/bin/external/protobuf_archive/src -isystem external/farmhash_archive/src -isystem bazel-out/k8-py2-opt/bin/external/farmhash_archive/src -isystem external/zlib_archive -isystem bazel-out/k8-py2-opt/bin/external/zlib_archive -DEIGEN_AVOID_STL_ARRAY -Iexternal/gemmlowp -Wno-sign-compare -fno-exceptions '-ftemplate-depth=900' -msse3 -pthread -fno-canonical-system-headers -Wno-builtin-macro-redefined '-D__DATE__="redacted"' '-D__TIMESTAMP__="redacted"' '-D__TIME__="redacted"' -c tensorflow/core/kernels/matrix_square_root_op.cc -o bazel-out/k8-py2-opt/bin/tensorflow/core/kernels/_objs/matrix_square_root_op/matrix_square_root_op.pic.o)
Execution platform: @bazel_tools//platforms:host_platform while evaluating ActionLookupData{actionLookupKey=//tensorflow/core/kernels:matrix_square_root_op BuildConfigurationValue.Key[06916201e0a2e3a731dd7c8fca228a97] false, actionIndex=1}
```

How can I fix this?

**- SOLUTION:**

**I had 2 GB RAM for the virtual machine. After increasing RAM to 8 GB, the build finished successfully.**

Comment: Looks weird, gcc was killed without any apparent reason. Maybe a transient error? Do you get this on every try?

Comment: Yes, I get it on every retry. I also tried to link out the .cache directory to another drive, where there is more space available, but I got the same result.

Comment: Adding more memory could help?

Comment: More memory wouldn't hurt. A shot in the dark, but I've seen processes getting mysteriously killed if I exhausted OS limits, e.g. ran out of disk or opened too many files.

Comment: Added further log informations. Does it help?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't. Looks like you have a 64bit CPU, that should be fine too. Also, unless it's already the case, can you try `./configure.py` again and configuring for the most basic settings?

Comment: Also, 5 hours...? Ouch. :(  Quick tip, use `--disk_cache` to speed up future builds.

Comment: I've had that kind of issues (too long compilation time, gcc killed) due to not having enough memory. I was compiling in a Docker container and after increasing the amount of memory I'd let it use it worked.

Comment: I had 2 GB RAM for the virtual machine. After increasing RAM to 8 GB, the build finished successfully.

Comment: László, could you post it as answer, so I can select as solution? Your comments directed me to find the right solution. Also thanks to @jdehesa, for the second idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mentioning the Solution here (Answer Section) even though it is present in Comments Section (Thanks to Laszlo and jdehesa) and the Questoin, for the **benefit of the Community**.

When tried to build Tensorflow using `Bazel` without `AVX2 Support`, The Error,

```
Nov 4 17:12:32 moodle37 kernel: [9773297.574293] traps: python2.7[4570] trap invalid opcode ip:7fb9b74bca59 sp:7ffdb7605e10 error:0 in libtensorflow_framework.so.1[7fb9b6d97000+18f8000]
```

and

```
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

will be resolved by **Increasing the RAM of Machine from 2GB RAM to 8GB**.

Happy Learning!